# can't load Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 in debug mode

Tags: powershell

Using VS Code with PowerShell and have a script where I am using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 provider to read an Excel sheet.  If I run the script in debugger mode inside the editor, I get the message:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered in the local machine."

The script works fine when run in the PowerShell command window and when run from the old ISE.

Comment: Hi Andrew and welcome to the site. Please, take a look at a tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour), it often helps in getting around easier. I am not a Windows user and haven't been for a long time, so just a suggestion, but are you certain editor "sees" or "is aware" of the ACE OLEDB provider? Has it ever been?

Comment: What is _the old ISE._? Also this sounds like a matter of running the x64 vs x86 shell?